# Bootstrap Modal box appears white

Tags: jquery, html, css, colors, bootstrap-modal

I created a modal box in the theme from [w3cschools.com - Simply Me](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_me.asp) and the modal box appears to be overlaid with white color. I have tried setting the z-index to -1 and 0 and 10000,  disabled backdrop, placed it above the navbar, but none of the given solutions work. Does anyone have a solution to this buggy modal issue.

[image: Bootstrap Modal Box is Completely white]

Here is the HTML code of my modal box.

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="ReSyncProfileModal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header bg-danger">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"> Hang On </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>You will have to wait for <span id="ReSyncProfileAfter"></span> seconds before you can "Recheck Profile Status" again.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer bg-danger">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Close </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Rather than the solution I would like to know what exactly is causing this issue. (Solution is also important :P )

Comment: The code looks fine without any problem so try to make a fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/vkawmfem/

Comment: Check your CSS for any overrides to the bootstrap for modal fade, modal-dialog modal-md, or modal-content that is creating the fade effect on your modal.

Answer (score 1):

You have changed something in CSS, Nothing wrong in HTML.

For `modal-title` class add `color:#000000` so that heading text would be appear in black color.

If you want to set color black for all the elements in-side modal, then add the `color` property for `modal-dialog`

Note : Please debug color property (In browsers press f12 and find out where the text color has set to white)